# How to change my local Git branch name to uppercase

Tags: git, github, version-control

I created a branch from my master (origin) and called it `TEST-101` (uppercase). I then worked on my branch and committed and pushed my changes up to origin. When I log in to Github, I can see I the branch I created.

I used git bash and checked out my local version of the branch, but I entered it in all lowercase: `test-101`. I then used Git Gui and committed my changes to the branch which was typed in lower case, and when I tried to push these changes it gave me an error:

```
POST git-receive-pack (390618 bytes)
remote: error: failed to lock refs/heads/test-101
Pushing to ht://example/example/example/example.git
To ht://example/example/example/example.git
! [remote rejected] test-101 -> test-101 (failed to lock)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://example/example/example/example.git'
```

(Please note that I have changed some private info in the error.)

I have done some reading, and it appears that my local branch being in lowercase and the remote branch being in uppercase may be causing an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
git branch -m test-101 tmp_branch
git checkout tmp_branch
git merge TEST-101 // make sure your data is up to date
git branch -D TEST-101
git branch -m tmp_branch TEST-101
```

`-m` option renames the branch, and `-D` option will delete the branch.

Answer (score 9):

The following solved the problem:

```
git branch -m test-101 tmp_branch
git branch -m tmp_branch TEST-101
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this in the future (like me) and finds that this does not work:

```
git branch -m branch_name tmp
git branch -m tmp BRANCH_NAME
```

you most likely have slashes in your branch name, e.g. `BRANCH/NAME`; if this is indeed the case, you will need to do something like the following (from the root directory of the repo):

```
git branch -m branch/name tmp
mv .git/refs/heads/branch .git/refs/heads/BRANCH
git branch -m tmp BRANCH/NAME
```

In the meantime I've submitted this to the Git mailing list and am waiting on responses.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the local branch to match the name of the remote branch (exactly, including capitalization) will resolve this, but you can also just `git push` explicitly specifying local and remote branches:

```
git push test-101:TEST-101
```